# Why doesn't my TextFinder replace text when using a regular expression?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got a sheet comprised of `lastName, firstName` pairs in one column, which I'm trying to convert into `firstName Lastname`.

When I use the following code, nothing happens on the sheet:

```js
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .createTextFinder('(\w+),\s(\w+).*?')
    .useRegularExpression(true)
    .matchEntireCell(false)
    .matchFormulaText(false)
    .replaceAllWith('$2 $1');
```

If I swap the regex for an actual string, it works fine.  Been testing my regex [on regexr.com](https://regexr.com/74o9o) and it matches everything I throw at it, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `createTextFinder()` method takes a text string rather than an actual regex. Internally, the function will use [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) to match text.

In JavaScript, you can use escapes to give a specific meaning to certain special characters. For example, to specify a newline character, you can use `'\n'`. That sequence will give a control character rather than a backslash and an 'n'. To get a backslash and an 'n', you would have to escape the escape, as in `'\\n'`. That will will give two characters, a backslash and an 'n'.

To make your code work, use double escapes, like this:

```
    .createTextFinder('(\\w+),\\s(\\w+).*?')
```

You can improve the expression a bit, like this:

```
    .createTextFinder('^[^\\w]*(\\w+),\\s*(\\w+)[\\s\\S]*')
```

Comment: doh!  tysm for the assist!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach

```
function funko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let o = vs.map((r, i) => {
    let m = r[0].match(/^(\w+),\s+(\w+)$/);
    return [m[1], m[2]];

  });
  sh.getRange(2,2,o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```

Data:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name | last | first |
| 2 | last1, first1 |  |  |
| 3 | last2, first2 |  |  |
| 4 | last3, first3 |  |  |

Output:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name | last | first |
| 2 | last1, first1 | last1 | first1 |
| 3 | last2, first2 | last2 | first2 |
| 4 | last3, first3 | last3 | first3 |